# Nginx Loadbalancer return 404

Tags: django, nginx, load-balancing, nginx-config

this is my nginx conf file

```
upstream django_servers {
   server serverone.domain.com:80;
   server servertwo.domain.com:80;
}
server {
  server_name server.domain.com;

  location /apiservice/api/ {
    proxy_pass http://django_servers;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

when I call the URLs directly from the browser it works fine(https://serverone.domain.com/apiservice/api/).

but if I use the load balancer it returns 404.

I am using the Django framework

```
location /apiservice/api/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/root/backend/app.sock;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
     }
```

this is the service nginx conf